# No signature of method: is applicable for argument types error in Groovy

Tags: groovy, gradle, cucumber

I am quite new to groovy and getting following error when running the below method. I am trying to pass xml file name and Map

### RD.groovy

```
    Given(~'^input currency "([^"]*)"$') { String baseCurr ->
     fromCurr = baseCurr
}
When(~'^insert end Currency "([^"]*)"$') { String tragetCurr ->
     toCurr = tragetCurr
}


Then(~'^get the expected end currency value "([^"]*)"$') { String result ->

    assert result == currCon(fromCurr, toCurr)


}

private currCon(fromCurr, toCurr)
{

    def binding = ["fromCurr": fromCurr, "toCurr": toCurr]
    response = Consumer.currConvert("request/CurrencyConvert.xml",binding)    --> This is line 119

    assert 200 == response.status
    return response.data.ConversionRateResult.toString()
}
```

### ClassA.groovy

```
    package abc.api.member

import abc.util.Log
import abc.util.TemplateUtil
import groovyx.net.http.ContentType
import abc.api.RestClient


class ClassA extends ClassB{

    ClassA(RestClient restClient) {
        super(restClient)
    }

def currConvert(String xmlFilename, Map binding) {

        return currencyConvertRequest(TemplateUtil.xmlFromTemplate(xmlFilename, binding))

    }

def currencyConvertRequest(xmlString) {

        def params = [path : 'CurrencyConvertor.asmx',
                headers: globeHeaders(),
                body: xmlString]
        return restClient.post(params)
    }
```

### Consumer.Groovy

```
package abc.api.member

import geb.Browser
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder
import abc.api.RestClient
import abc.browser.member.Admin


class Consumer {
    Browser browser
    String token
    String userId

    @Delegate
    private ClassA classA

 Consumer(url) {
        browser = new Browser()
        browser.baseUrl = baseUrl(url)
        restClient = new RestClient(url)

        classA =  new ClassA(restClient)    
    }

private baseUrl(url) {
        URI uri = URI.create(url)
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
        URI result =builder.setHost(uri.host). //
                setPath(uri.path). //
                setPort(uri.port). //
                setScheme(uri.scheme). 
                setUserInfo("Cons", "pbiCons").build()

        return result.toURL().toString()
    }
```

Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: abc.api.consumer.Consumer.currConvert() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [request/globe/CurrencyConvert.xml, [fromCurr:AUD, ...]]
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:51)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
            at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
            at RD.currCon(RD.groovy:119)
```

After searching the issue it turned out its a common issue. Couldn't figure out though. Because all solutions are subjective.

Just curious where I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: That's really weird. Can you try casting it to String or use the method `toString()` or use a single quote instead of double quote and see if it works ? what version of Groovy are you using ?

Comment: `Groovy Version: 2.1.9 JVM: 1.7.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 7 ` I tried single quote and `toString() ` as well. But no luck

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`currConvert` is an instance method, but it's being called as if it was a static method.

Comment: Basically I `@Delegate `  `ClassA.groovy ` in `Consumer.groovy ` and created an instance before executing the `currConvert `. Would that do?

Comment: You'll still need to get rid of the `Consumer.`, as `currConvert` is an instance method.

Comment: I did the change still get `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: RD.currConvert() is applicable for argument types: (org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [request/globe/CurrencyConvert.xml, [fromCurr:AUD, ...]] `

Comment: Please update your question and include *all* necessary information to reproduce the problem. For example, the question doesn't mention the use of `@Delegate` at all. It also doesn't show the `Consumer` class (although it's referenced from the code), and leaves one wondering why the file is called `ClassA.groovy` rather than `Consumer.groovy`.

Comment: Sorry for less information. Added all the info as possible. Basically in here `RD.groovy ` is the step definition file in cucumber. Hopfully this gives better picture. `Consumer.groovy ` is the class where I `delegated ` `ClassA.groovy `

Comment: `currConvert` is an instance method. Instead of `Consumer.currConvert(...)`, it has to be something like `new Consumer(someUrl).currConvert(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem like this :

```
class Example {
  static void main (String [] args) {
   printMessage(obj)
  }
  def printMessage(obj) {
  }
}
```

I was getting the same exception at printMessage(obj).
It got fixed after changing it to like this :

```
class Example {
  static void main (String [] args) {
    new Example().printMessage(obj)
   }
   def printMessage(obj) {
   }
 }
```